# Time attack-resilient comparison in Python < 2.7.7

Tags: python, security, python-2.7

In python 2.7.7 `hmac.compare_digest` was introduced which is intended to provide string comparison resilient to time attacks.

Sadly, 2.7.7 is still pretty recent and many systems have older versions, including Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there a way to compare authentication strings in such systems without having to require the user to compile Python from source (and recompile it periodically to keep with security updates)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to securely verify an HMAC in Python 2.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168819/how-to-securely-verify-an-hmac-in-python-2-7)

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid shortcircuiting. Something like

```
sum(i != j for i, j in zip(hmac1.digest(), hmac2.digest()))
```

The same caveat as `compare_digest` applies:

> **Note:** If a and b are of different lengths, or if an error occurs, a
>   timing attack could theoretically reveal information about the types
>   and lengths of a and b–but not their values.

Comment: What are ``hmac1`` and ``hmac2``?

Comment: they are the hmac objects you wish to compare digests of

Comment: I asked about comparing strings, not HMACs.

Comment: digests are just strings. so `sum(i != j for i, j in zip(string1, string2))`

Comment: Is it possible to compare characters in constant time in Python? In the bug tracker they didn't look very convinced about that. http://bugs.python.org/issue15061